# changing text on user mouseover

Tags: usability

Is it recommended to have a text change on a mouseover action?
For example: 
Title: Coupons
Mouseover title: Manage your Coupons.

I am thinking it should be enough to have only an underline effect but we're going through discussions here.

Comment: Is this for a header or navigation menu item?

Comment: keep in mind that touch interfaces keep gradually killing the ancient art of handling mouseover.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to convey extra information then you should use tooltip rather than changing the text itself. However, this doesn't help users on touchscreen devices.

Another option in this case could be to have a information icon ("i") next to the option which displays the tooltip when hovered over or clicked.

Another reason for *not* doing it is that changing text may well change the layout of your UI causing other elements to change position.

Answer (score 3):

As short answer to your question:
No, it is not recommended to change text on mouseover.

Mouseover behaviour is basically to say: **This is your current mouse target.**

If the target changes drastically from what it was before hovering it would confuse users.

However if it gives any additional value and the change isn't too shocking, do it.

**Mouseovers should not be used gratuitously**, use it for highlighting active hotspots and links, and giving the user useful information.

I would not hide an action under a non-self-explanatory menu item. If the item is "Settings", it's quite clear that you can adjust settings there. But if it's "Coupons", is it just a listing of coupons, or can you purchase coupons there, or manage them, or both?

What about users with no mouse? User shouldn't be left feeling stupid.